# Fix the last element of a GridBagLayout to the bottom of the page

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I have a GridBagLayout. The last element (startButton) jumps up and down depending on how much text there is in the above text box. Is there any way of fixing its position? I tried changing PAGE_START to PAGE_END, but that didn't do anything.

```
contentPanel.add(titleText, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(50, 100, 0, 100), 0, 0));
        contentPanel.add(expText, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, new Insets(120, 100, 00, 100), 0, 0));
        contentPanel.add(buttonsPanel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, new Insets(120, 100, 0, 100), 0, 0));

        contentPanel.add(userText, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, new Insets(120, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
        contentPanel.add(startButton, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, new Insets(180, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));

        contentPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue(), new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1,
                GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
```

Comment: I don't see a PAGE_END in the code you posted.  You could try creating a JPanel with a BorderLayout, putting the content panel in the center, and putting a button panel in south.

Comment: Well it didn;t have any effect. I tried it like this: contentPanel.add(startButton, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, new Insets(180, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it like this:

```
contentPanel.add(startButton, new GridBagConstraints(0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER, new Insets(-180, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't try this in your context, but this should make it stick to the bottom:

```
contentPanel.add(startButton,
   new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END,
            GridBagConstraints.CENTER, new Insets(180, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
```